# Get the middle elements from List in scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm new to scheme , can someone please give me ideas on how to get , "the middle element from a list?"

Comment: Interesting question (especially if you only want to traverse the list only once). What should happen if the list has an even number of elements? What should happen if the list is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my solution. It's based on a [tortoise-and-hare algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) (which is used in any kind of list traversal where you need to detect circular lists), so it doesn't do any more work than a sane list traversal has to do anyway. :-)

```
(define (middle-elements lst)
  (if (null? lst) '()
      (let loop ((tortoise lst)
                 (hare (cdr lst)))
        (cond ((eq? tortoise hare) #f)
              ((null? hare) (list (car tortoise)))
              ((null? (cdr hare)) (list (car tortoise) (cadr tortoise)))
              (else (loop (cdr tortoise) (cddr hare)))))))
```

It covers the following cases:

- If given an empty list, returns an empty list.
- If given a list with an odd number of elements, returns a singleton list with the middle element.
- If given a list with an even number of elements, returns a list with the two middle elements.
- If given a circular list, returns `#f`.
- If given an improper list (including a non-list), summons nasal demons.

Comment: Thanks, This got me going . But what happens if the parameter given by the user is not a list? Can we display a warning like:(show " USAGE: (middle-element [LIST])")) maybe?

Comment: You're doing the same course as Nathalie D, aren't you? :-P Same non-standard `show` function, same usage message, etc. In my honest opinion, the best way to check parameter types is via Racket's [contracts](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contracts.html). I don't know contracts very well, so I can't help with that. And I definitely can't help with the `show` thing your course uses, since that's not even standard Scheme.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I'm curious, why is necessary the third case in the `cond`? I did a couple of tests and the first case was enough for finding a cycle. Can you provide a counterexample?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez You're absolutely right, it's totally redundant, now that I think about it. Once the third case matches, then by definition, the first case will match the next time through the loop.