# Way of returning median value of a list? (scheme)

Tags: list, scheme, median

I'm attempting to make a procedure named `median` that takes the median value of a list. If the list is even, then I will return the two middle numbers. I have the logic all thought out in my head, but I'm not sure how to complete it. NOTE: I am trying to avoid using list-ref, as it would trivialize the problem.
So far, my code looks like the following.

```
(define (median lst)
(if (null? lst)
   '()
    (if (even? lst) ; ends here
```

Now, my approach to the problem is this.

```
Odd #- Return the value of the "car#" that's in place of (/ (+ (length lst) 1) 2)
3; 2nd car      (1 100 3)    => 100
5; 3rd car      (1 2 100 4 5)  => 100
7; 4th car      (1 2 3 100 5 6 7)  => 100
Even # - Return the value of the "car#" that's in place of (/ (length lst) 2) AND (+ (/ (length lst) 2) 1)
2; 1st and 2nd car         (1 2) => 1 2
4; 2nd and 3rd car         (1 20 30 4) => 20 30
```

However, I cant seem to come up with a way that could recursively implement this pseudocode.

EDIT: Not sure if anyone is still out there willing to help, but I ended up writing an iterative procedure that will take the median index value for any odd list. My trouble now is implementing something that will make the code work for an even list, and also something that doesn't return the value in a list:

```
(define (median-index-odd lst)
    (define (median-index-iter1 lst times_carred)
        (if (null? lst)
           '()
            (if (= times_carred (/ (+ (length lst) 1) 2)) 
                (list (car lst))            
                (median-index-iter1 (cdr lst) (+ 1 times_carred)))))
                (median-index-iter1 lst 0))
```

I've also came up with a seperate procedure for finding the median index when the list is even:

```
(define (median-index-even lst)
    (define (median-index-iter2 lst times_carred)
        (if (null? lst)
           '()
            (if (= times_carred (/ (length lst) 2)) 
                (list (car lst) (cadr lst))            
                (median-index-iter2 (cdr lst) (+ 1 times_carred)))))
                (median-index-iter2 lst 0))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the middle elements from List in scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306626/get-the-middle-elements-from-list-in-scheme).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like homework.

The straightforward solution includes `list-sort` (`rnrs / sorting`) unless it's already sorted, `length` to get the list length, `list-tail` to get the list from half and `car` for odd, and an additional `cadr` for the even list. You use `let` to do something with intermediate values.

Edit in some code even if you get it right or not. For the latter we can help you more.

Comment: No, there's an approach that does not use `length`. :-) See the dupe link I posted, it contains an answer I wrote for a similar question.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young True, but it's less straightforward. The differences between them is little. Eg. a 100 million element list in ikarus. t&h used 0.80s while length+list-tail used 1.10s. I.e. the straightforward solution performs pretty well for most lists and rewriting it using T&H is fun, but premature optimizing.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (median L)
 (if (null? L)
     (error "No median of empty list")
     (let loop ((L1 L) (L2 L))
       (cond ((null? (cdr L2)) (car L1))
             ((null? (cddr L2)) (list (car L1) (cadr L1)))
             (else (loop (cdr L1) (cddr L2))))))
```

split into two lists take the first one at a time, the second two at a time

Comment: Basically the same as [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13308315/13), except that I took care to return a list even in the single median case, so that there's no information lossage if the elements are themselves lists (and also allows me to return an empty list when given an empty list, rather than throwing an error). :-)

Comment: Your's is a little different because it checks for cycles, but the logic is the same. Honestly I read the question, was like "ooh, I know this", read Sylwester's answer and then posted mine. Missed the little bitty comment.