# How to write a scheme procedure for mean and median of a list?

Tags: scheme

I need to write a basic scheme procedure that can find the median of a list and another for the mean.

This is what I've come up with so far:

Mean:

```
(define (mean lst)
   (if (null? lst) ()
       (+ 1 (car lst) (mean (cdr lst))))
```

I know I need to divide my the length somewhere but not sure how to do so. My thought process for this is to add each element to the stack of the list and then divide my the length of the list?

Median:

I'm not sure where to start for median.I know I need to determine if the list has an odd number of elements or even, so to do that I've come up with

```
(define (median lst)
  (if (integer? (/ (length lst) 2)  ;which is the one for even
```

I don't know if I need another procedure to get me to the middle of the list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628281/way-of-returning-median-value-of-a-list-scheme) question.

Answer (score 1):

The `median` procedure was already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628281/way-of-returning-median-value-of-a-list-scheme).

Calculating the `mean` is simple, just add all the elements and divide by the length of the list, the only special case to take care of is when the list is empty (because that will lead to a division by zero: the length is zero!), return an appropriate value indicating this.

By now you should definitely know how to add all the elements in a list, check with your instructor in case of doubts, but it's a basic operation, it shouldn't be a problem.